# Issue in connecting kafka from outside

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using hortonwork Sandbox for kafka server
trying to connect kafka from eclipse with java code .
Use this configuration to connect to producer to send the message

```
metadata.broker.list=sandbox.hortonworks.com:45000
serializer.class=kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder
zk.connect=sandbox.hortonworks.com:2181
request.required.acks=0
producer.type=sync
```

where sandbox.hortonworks.com is sandboxname to whom i connect

in kafka server.properties I changed this configuration

```
host.name=sandbox.hortonworks.com

advertised.host.name=System IP(on which my eclipse is running)
advertised.port=45000
```

did the port forwarding also ,

I am able to connect to kafka server from eclipse but while sending the message get the exception 
Exception"Failed to send messages after 3 tries."

Comment: advertised.host.name should be a public hostname or public IP of the server itself where Kafka is running not the hostname of your client where eclipse is running, further you can comment out host.name to bind server into all interfaces.

Comment: if my kafka is running on Unix box ,it's a virtual machine and my desktop is hosting both Virtual Machine and Eclipse . Then advertised.host.name can be desktop IP addresss or not please confirm

Comment: You can set a hostname in your virtual box using hostname "XXXXX" command. once done, you can modify your hosts file in the desktop to point to XXXXX. I did not get a chance to test this in a virtual box though, but I guess it will make a sense

Answer (score 7):

First make sure you have configured host-only network for your Hortonworks Sandbox VM as described here:

http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/use-host-only-networking-for-the-virtual-machine/

After doing this your sandbox VM should get a IP (e.g. 192.168.56.101) and it should be reachable from your host via SSH like

```
$ ssh root@192.168.56.101
```

Then open Ambari at http://192.168.56.101:8080/ and change the Kafka configuration to

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:6667
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.56.101:6667
```

The latter property must be added in the section "Custom kafka-broker" (See also http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/ambari-alerts-how-to-change-kafka-port/).

Then start/restart Kafka via Ambari. You should now be able to access Kafka from outside the Hortonworks Sandbox VM. You can test this (from outside of the sandbox VM) using e.g. the Kafka console producer from the Kafka distribution like

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic test --broker-list 192.168.56.101:6667
```

Comment: to compliment this answer, adding a link to my blog post https://boristyukin.com/connecting-to-kafka-on-virtualbox-from-windows/

Answer (score 1):

After almost one week of config tweeking, I finally get it work. Similar to asmaier's answer but if you are using cloud server like me:  Azure Sandbox-hdp, try to pub/sub thru remote consumer/producer.

## In azure:

first SSH into your azure 
in Ambari Web-UI localhost:8080, add

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:6667
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:6667
```

in terminal @root, Set up docker port forwarding like hortonwroks instruction page [sandbox](https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/sandbox-port-forwarding-guide/section/4/)

```
vi start_scripts/start_sandbox.sh
```

add port 6667 on the list

## On your PC:

first SSH into your azure plus tunneling 6667.

then write in cmd: or your run own java/c# script

```
kafka\bin\windows>kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

Only thing that bothers me right now is I cant find a way to make kafka push messages directly to a real public IP/ Azure. It seems Data traffic thru broker can only operate inside the docker internally.

Comment: this won't work, I tested, Kafka services both in Docker Version HDP and Virtualbox HDP  won't be connected from Host Machine (Windows 10) in my case, all the port are open. I can  get the topic list within IDE by connecting to the zookeeper service in HDP, but not Kafka, I tested I am able to connect Kafka service running in Docker for Windows (Confluence version), nice and smooth, As for HDP, I believe added advertised.listeners and Host IP to the Kafka Configuration in Ambari, services restarted, but still failed to connect, manually settings in Unix  will be flushed by settings in Ambari.