# Apache Kafka : Producer -Consume API not running on GCP

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-producer-api, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to run my producer and consumer api on Kafka cluster but it is not working.

1) Zookeeper is running on one GCP VM instance

2) Kafka is running on another GCP VM instance

**Steps Followed:**

**Step 1)** Running Zookeeper using the following command:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

**Zookeeper.properties:**

```
#the directory where the snapshot is stored.

dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper 

#the port at which the clients will connect 

clientPort=2181 

#disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a     non-production config 

maxClientCnxns=0 

# In milliseconds 

tickTime=2000 

# In ticks

initLimit=10 
syncLimit=5 
maxClientCnxns=30 

# All Zookeeper servers need to be aware of other Zookeepers part of the cluster 

server.1=zook-1:2888:3888
```

**Note : zook-1 is the name of the Zookeeper instance**

**Step 2)**

Running Kafka on another GCP VM instance as :

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-li de-kafka-1:9092 --topic test
```

server.properties:

```
 ############################# Server Basics ############################# # The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker. 

broker.id=0 
############################ Zookeeper ############################# #

# root directory for all kafka znodes. 

zookeeper.connect=zook-1:2181 

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper 

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000 

host.name=de-kafka-1
```

**Step 3)**

Running producer api on the Kafka instance from Step 2 (using another SSH tunnel) as follows :

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list de-kafka-1:9 092 --topic    test
```

Note : Here de-kafka-1 is the name of the GCP Kafka VM instance I have tried and replaced de-kafka-1 with External IP of de-Kafka-1 instance, localhost, zook-1 (Name of Zookeeper VM instance), external IP of zook-1 vm instance

```
Error: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is   expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N Sending msg1 sending msg2 

Error: error when sending message to topic test single node with key:   null, value: 5 bytes with error (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.errorloggingcallback)org.apache.kafka.common.errors.timeoutexception: failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

**Step 4:**

Running Consumer API on Kafka instance (using third SSH tunnel):

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server de-kafka-1:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Would appreciate if anyone could help on this. Thanks

Comment: try to run `telnet zook-1 2181` from the kafka vm, and if succeed type `stats` and press enter. this will check your kafka-zookepper connectivity and the status of the zookeeper.

Comment: @Gal Thanks for your reply, Here is what i am getting:                                                     ------------------------                                          'Zookeeper version: 3.4.9-1757313, built on 08/23/2016 06:50 GMT
Clients:                                                                              /xx.xxx.x.xx:45284[1](queued=0,recved=275,sent=277)
/xx.xxx.x.xx:45384[0](queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)
Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/6
Received: 276
Sent: 277
Connections: 2
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x113
Mode: standalone
Node count: 36
Connection closed by foreign host.'

Comment: @Gal Any clue what that signifies

Comment: looks good, `Mode: standalone` means you're running zk standalone mode. try to run `netstat -nlp | grep 9092` on the kafka vm and post the output..

Comment: @Gal  tcp6       0      0 xx.xxx.x.xx:9092        :::*             LISTEN      890/java       . Here is the output after running netstat -nlp | grep 9092

Comment: edit your Kafka broker `server.properties` file and change the `broker.id` field (to '15' for example), restart Kafka and recheck..

Comment: @Gal Error I am getting after changs : `FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
kafka.common.InconsistentBrokerIdException: Configured broker.id 15 doesn't match stored broker.id 0 in meta.properties. If you moved your data, make sure your configured broker.id matches. If you intend to create a new broker, you should remove all data in your data directories (log.dirs).
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.getBrokerId(KafkaServer.scala:691)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:194)`

Comment: @Gal Updated log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-2, and Kafka started running. But when running producer API with :  **bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list de-kafka-1:9092 --topic test** Error : `ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 4 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-0: 1517 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time`

Comment: @Gal Running Producer API with : **bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list zook-1:9092 --topic test** Error : `Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 2 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.`

Comment: @Gal On a side note, when I run Kafka, zookeeper logs throw this : `INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0xxxxxxxx01 type:create cxid:0xx4 zxid:0xxxf txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/id
s Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/ids (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)`  Since its just Info, I have not been looking into it

Answer (score 0):

Try to create topic before producing `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper zook-1:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test`.

If its not working read about `zkCli.sh` script [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/zookeeper/zookeeper_cli.htm%20with%20this%20script%20you%20can) - with this script you can check if the broker is registered in the zookeeper.

If you still have a problems, and you trying to produce from outside the kafka cluster, try to read about `advertised.listeners` property [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161313/issue-in-connecting-kafka-from-outside).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But Topic test is already created. Additionally broker is registered on Zookeeper `[root@de-kafka-1 bin]# ./zookeeper-shell.sh zook-1:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/ids"
Connecting to zook-1:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled
WATCHER::
WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[10]` . Additionally, I am producing it within the same kafka cluster.