# can't access kafka outside the docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, apache-kafka, ambari, hdp

I installed the latest HDP into the docker container.

```
docker ps
>hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
>hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
```

Kafka broker is running at **6667** port that it's **working fine.**

```
   >ssh hdfs@sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com -p 2222
   > echo "send test message" | kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:6667 --topic hotelReservation > /dev/null
   >kafka-console-consumer.sh   --bootstrap-server sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:6667 --topic test --from-beginning
```

The only problem is that I don't have access to the Kafka broker outside the docker container.

**More information for troubleshooting:**

I verified that all the ports are open **local machine -> proxy -> hdp**

**HDP  Server:**

```
      hostname -I
      172.18.0.2

      netstat -vatn | grep 6667
      tcp        0      0 172.18.0.2:6667         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

**Proxy Server**

```
  hostname -I
  172.18.0.3

  nmap 172.18.0.2 -p 6667
  6667/tcp open  irc

  netstat -vatn | grep 6667
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6667            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

**My Local  machine:**

```
nmap sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com -p 6667
    Host is up (0.000064s latency).
    rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost
    PORT     STATE SERVICE
    6667/tcp open  irc
```

Note: 6668 is open too.

included default stream conf (/etc/nginx/conf/**stream.d**/**tcp-hdp.conf**):

```
server {
  listen 6668;
  proxy_pass sandbox-hdp:6667;
}
```

So I decided to create new config  the http: /etc/nginx/conf/**stream.d**/**tcp-hdp.conf**

```
server {
  listen 6667;
  server_name sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://sandbox-hdp:6667;
  }
}
```

**Note:** I read ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161313/issue-in-connecting-kafka-from-outside)) that I should use advertised.listeners to access broker outside the doctor:

```
>listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:6667
>advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://172.18.0.2:6667
```

but I 'm sure that's incorrect for my case. I have access in this network, the problem is some type of **Nginx mapping only**.

Comment: It seems from your question that you're using nginx, but it's not clear quite how or why? If you want to access Kafka broker across a network you need to configure your advertised.listeners correctly: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: It's The Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP) default Architecture.

Comment: I added advertised.listeners=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:6667  in Ambari UI custom kafka broker option. I also enabled 6667 / 2181 inside HDP host http-conf. file, proxy-deploy.sh, but the ports are open if I telnet them from Windows Host OS, ( my Virtualbox settings is NAT, forwarding rules ports open for them), I still can't consume message from Kafka in HDP, I used the only domain name sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:6667, someone help ?  It's been a month and it's really frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Run the following command to find **hortonworks/sandbox-proxy** container id.

```
docker ps
```

Log in to the proxy server

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
```

add new mapping in the nginx

```
cd /etc/nginx/conf.stream.d
vim tcp-hdp.conf
```

config:

```
server {
  listen 6667;
  proxy_pass sandbox-hdp:6667;
}
```

reload nginx mapping:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

Test:

```
> ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:6668 --topic topicName --from-beginning
> echo "msg" | ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:6668 --topic topicName > /dev/nul
```

The problem was that 6667:6667 mapping was missing. Now brokers are access both 6667 and 6668 ports.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day. Just out of curiosity, i tried accessing `./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:6668` before adding 6667:6667, but it did not work any idea why. Even after adding `6667:6667`, `./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:6668` does not work only `kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:6667` works